# Android L - Sliding menu that overlaps actionbar

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, drawerlayout

I am working on Android L trying to implement a drawer menu that overlaps the action bar. I have done it the normal way where it appears under the action bar, as described here: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/.

It was done in the google IO 2014 app and I would like to replicate it. I have been looking through the code (https://github.com/google/iosched) but I can't figure out how they done it.

Here is an image:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea how they done it?

Comment: I have downloaded the same link (http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/.) and checked in L but I am nt facing the issue u mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain this you have to use the new Toolbar.

You can use a layout like this:

```
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize" />
```

Then in your activity you can do:

```
 Toolbar mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
 if (mActionBarToolbar != null) {
       mActivity.setActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
 }
```

Finally you have to setup the toolbar to work with the navigation drawer:

```
if (mActionBarToolbar != null) {
     mActionBarToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer);
     mActionBarToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) {
                      mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
                 } else {
                      mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
                 }
            }
      });
 }
```

Pay attention because currently the new Toolbar class is only API-21.